# Add a custom VBO action

Tags: views

I want to add a custom [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) action.

It display in the actions list of the view, it should like a tree, like this:

-Add Role-

RoleA

RoleB

-Remove Role-

RoleA

RoleB

And When I select RoleA(-Remove Role-), check some users, click the submit.

The users checked should be removed RoleA.

How can I code a custom VBO action like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom VBO action by implementing `hook_action_info()` hook. Here are some useful links which can help you achieve what you want:

1. [Views Bulk Operations development guide (Drupal 7)](https://drupal.org/node/2052067)
2. [Programmatically adding and removing roles to users in Drupal](http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/programmatically-adding-roles)
3. [HOWTO assign a user to a role programatically](https://drupal.org/node/28379)

additionally, [Examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) can help you to learn about `Actions`.